# How to migrate Lotus Notes Database to DB2?

Tags: lotus-domino

Is there any way to migrate data of Lotus Notes Database (.NSF) to DB2 or MS SQL? I am currently working on data migration which main goal is to migrate the content of website (running on domino server) to WebSphere Portal.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to migrate data: Export as CSV / Import, writing a LotusScript- Agent to directly write your data to the SQL- Database using JDBC or ODBC, writing a program in any other language using com or any other provided interface to get the data, buying a product to do so...

This question is far to broad to be answered en detail. The answer fitting your question best is: Yes, there are a lot ways to do this...

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I installed the ODBC for Lotus Notes and seems I got all my data in every view :) You can vote my question you to help me increasing my reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the structure of the data in the DB its hard to tell, but I would build a kind of middle-ware and use [NotesSQL](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/products/notesdomino/notessql/) in order to fetch something from Notes and then push it to something else (e.g. mySQL).

Comment: Similar answer to Torsten Link but this one is very helpful. Thanks for providing the link for NotesSQL. I already installed the NotesSQL together with ODBC for Lotus Notes and able to fetch my data from every view of my lotus notes application :) I am not able to vote this up due to insufficient reputation. You can vote my question you to help me increasing my reputation.

Comment: yes its similar, but this provided a link to NotesSQL so somebody else doesn´t need to search for a product and got a direct hit ;-).